# PyGObject Display csv on textview

Tags: python, pygobject

I would like to find a way to display CSV files on a TextView GTK+3 with Python..

I've tested alot of stuff but i can't make it work

```
def on_button_program_list2_clicked(self, button, data=None):
    self.window_list.show() # this is the window that contains the textview widget
    self.text_view= self.builder.get_object("textview_list")
    list_path=Data_Location+"/program-data/programs_to_install.csv"
    list = csv.reader(open(list_path))
    self.text_view.set_text(list)
```

If it's possible, i would like to display the text in rows, and not as the python csv reader:

```
['string1'],['string2'],['string3']
```

but as

```
String1    String2    String3
```

Thanks so much!

---

Trying more stuff..

```
def on_button_program_list2_clicked(self, button, data=None):

    self.window_list.show()
    self.textview1= self.builder.get_object("textview_list")
    list_path=Data_Location+"/program-data/programs_to_install.csv"
    lists = csv.reader(open(list_path))

    lists = csv.reader(open(list_path))

    text_buffer= Gtk.TextBuffer()

    for item in lists:
        output = item[0]+"      "+item[1]+"     "+item[2]+"     "+item[3]   
        end_iter = text_buffer.get_end_iter()
        text_buffer.insert(end_iter, output)

    self.textview1 = Gtk.TextView(buffer=text_buffer)
```

But i'm struggling to display it on the textview widget. Also if there would be a better way of displaying the items in rows instead of spaces it would be great!

Comment: I used a treeview to display the csv. It is much more adequate than a textview to do this task, but I guess that the textview question could remain open..

Answer (score 0):

You retrieving lists, so just get text from it:
(untested)

```
lists = csv.reader(open(list_path))
output = ''

for alist in lists:
    output += alist + '\n'
self.text_view.set_text(output)
```

For output in one line omit the newline symbol.
Does this help?

Comment: Maybe, im trying to find the problem, im getting this error:                                                             File "fresh_install", line 836, in on_button_program_list2_clicked
    output += alist + '\n'
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: so, you got a tuple of lists.

change code to

`    output += alist[0]`

Does it do the trick?

Comment: I think that it works because im not getting anymore that error, but i'm getting the error
self.text_view.set_text(output)
AttributeError: 'TextView' object has no attribute 'set_text', i was getting this error before, and i don't understand why

Comment: I'm also trying with gtk_text_view_set_buffer(output) but i get the same error AttributeError: 'TextView' object has no attribute 'gtk_text_view_set_buffer', and this is on the GTK+ 3 reference manual

Comment: I'm only guessing, since I dont do anything with gtk.
From the docs:


`textbuffer = self.text_view.get_buffer()`
then
`textbuffer.set_text(string)`

Comment: To be honest i don't understand the docs, but i found it too. The problem with that is that it only display the last item of the list. So i searched how to add items at the last line, and i found this                                                        end_iter = self.textbuffer.get_end_iter()
self.textbuffer.insert(end_iter, output)                          but the result is that i get all the lists in the same row